# Show that $\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the independent variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be geometrically distributed with parameter $0\le p_i \le 1$ where $i=1, \dots, n$. Show that $Y=\min {\{\ X_1, \dots, X_n} \} $ is geometrically distributed and give its parameter $p$.

$$1-\operatorname{CDF}(X)=P(X_i\ge x)=\sum_{k=x}^\infty p_i(1-p_i)^k$$

$$P(X_i\ge x)=p_i(1-p_i)^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p_i)^k$$

$$P(X_i\ge x)=(1-p_i)^x$$

and same logic for $Y$

$$1-\operatorname{CDF}(Y)=P(Y \ge y)=P(X_1 \ge y)P(X_2 \ge y)\dots P(X_n \ge n)$$
$$P(Y \ge y)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)^y$$

Can I state now that $Y \sim \operatorname{Geom}(n, 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i))$?

But I still don't understand $Y$ conceptually, ok I found its $p$ but am I able to answer questions like what's the prob. that $Y=X_n$ ?

EDIT:

it may not be that obvious that $Y \sim \operatorname{Geom}(n, 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i))$, so I'll be explicit:

$$P(Y=y)=P(Y \ge y) - P(Y \ge y+1)$$
$$P(Y=y)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-p_i)^y - \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-p_i)^y\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-p_i)$$
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-p_i) = \alpha $$
$$P(Y=y)=\alpha^y - \alpha^y \alpha$$
$$P(Y=y)=(1-(1-\alpha))^y (1 - \alpha) \Rightarrow Y \sim \operatorname{Geom}(n, 1-\alpha) $$

Comment: I don't think the idea of the problem is that the $X_i$ are i.i.d.r.v... otherwise the $p_i$ would be all the same and the $i$ would be meaningless. You're reasoning is fine even if they're just independent.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum in the exercise they say that $X_i$ are independent and follow the geom. distr. with param. $p_i$ (I removed the i.i.d. part of the question now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you should be able at this point to answer which is
$$P(Y=X_1)$$
or so. You found that $Y \sim \mathcal G (\tilde p)$ for certain $\tilde p$, but to calculate probabilities of events involving both $Y$ and some $X_n$ you would need to know the *joint distribution* of $Y$ and $X_n$ (for instance, if you knew the joint CDF, $F_{X_n,Y}(x,y)$ you could calculate some probabilities since it is defined as
$F_{X_n,Y}(x,y)=P(X_n\le x \wedge Y \le y)$
(actually you could calculate potentially almost any probability involving both variables).

Only if $X_n$ and $Y$ were independent it would be enough to know each distribution separately, since in that case
$F_{X_n,Y}(x,y)=F_{X_n}(x)\cdot F_Y(y),$
but... in this case $Y$ is clearly dependent with any of the $X_i$.

Your calculations seem right, by the way.